# centos: update tzdata for new DST rules in Brazil.

Tags: linux, dst

Brazil looks like being changing its DST rules again (next transition date was initially oct'20th, changed to nov'4th and now to nov'18th ). 
Looking at ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz the last update is 2018e, which doesn't include this last change.

Any clue on how to handle this for both linux tzdata and openjdk tzdata-java ?

thanks.

Comment: That has been asked yesterday, hence the duplicate.